# Windows 7 x64 "upgrade" repair fails (also Windows Update error 800B0001)

Tags: windows-7, windows, 64-bit, upgrade, windows-update

**Update:** The original issue that spawned this question has been fixed, so this is now moot. I was unable to use Windows Update, as it'd throw error 800B0001 when I tried to use it, and would also ask to update Windows Update (which would also fail). After performing some manual patches and installing [Microsoft FixIt 50528](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/822798), it now works again! :)

---

I've been running into issues with Windows Update, which I can't seem to fix. The hotfixes don't work, nor does the Windows update readyness tool, or the manual SP1 upgrade. I get various esoteric errors which nobody seems to have a fix for. Looks like some of the update cache is corrupt and digital signatures seem to be broken on some packages / Windows Update components.

Long story short, I have discovered the only option is to do a repair operation on the OS, to repair everything. It's so corrupt that only a complete replacement will fix it.

According to various sources (including MSKB) one can perform a repair by running an in-place upgrade.

I've got the Windows 7 Ultimate retail disc, which I've inserted into my machine. I ran `setup.exe` and went through in the following order:

- Install now
- Go online to get latest updates (I've also tried not getting updates)
- Wait for updates to be downloaded
- Select Windows 7 Ultimate (x64 architecture) and click next
- Accept the T&Cs, click next
- Click Upgrade

At this point it spends a minute on the "checking compatibility" screen, after which I get the following error:

> The following issues are preventing Windows from upgrading. Cancel the upgrade, complete each task, and then restart the upgrade to continue.
>
> - You can’t upgrade 64-bit Windows to a 32-bit version of Windows. To upgrade, obtain a 64-bit version of the installation disc, or go online to see how to install Windows 7 and keep your files and settings.
> - 32-bit Windows cannot be upgraded to a 64-bit version of Windows. To upgrade, obtain a 32-bit version of the Windows installation disc.

It also mentions a warning about potential conflicts with a storage driver and VS2010, but that doesn't seem to be the blocking issue.

My *currently installed* version of Windows is Ultimate 64-bit (absolutely sure of this) and the disc is definitely a x86 / x64 combined Ultimate retail disc. There seem to be a few people who have run into this (e.g. [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/283463/compatibility-issue-before-upgrading-windows-7-64-bit-to-windows-7-64-bit-servic)), but I've not seen any answers. I've checked the event viewer, but can't spot anything in there that's related.

Any idea how I can get this working?

**P.S:** Just to pre-empt the inevitable "are you *suuuuuuuuuuuuure* it's x64 Ultimate?" questions:

[image: System Info]

[image: Installer architecture options]

Comment: I recommend you use an original 64-bit Win7 DVD instead of this combined/AIO version you've created.

Comment: I've not created any "combined" disc. The original retail DVD comes with both x86 and x64.

Comment: Is this an OEM version or something? The boxed retail version I have definitely came with two separate DVDs.

Comment: The machine is a self-build, and Windows 7 Ultimate was provided as a bundle with the motherboard. It came in a retail box, with the normal looking insides, and only has one DVD. The only difference is that the OS comes with a pre-installed SLIC and key, like an OEM, for auto-activation.

Comment: Ok, so is it possible for you to test with a 64-bit only version from [here](http://superuser.com/questions/78761/where-do-i-download-windows-7-legally-from-microsoft)? If that doesn't help then most likely the current installation is corrupted in such a way that a clean install is the only solution. (BTW, I hope you tried `sfc /scannow` already before attempting the repair install?)

Comment: There's no SP1 integration on this disc - it's a standard pre-SP1 DVD. Doesn't look like there's a download for Ultimate x64 without SP1. I actually tried an ISO of that (had one handy from setting up a VM) and it said I need to install SP1 on the box before trying to upgrade, which fails due to afforementioned Windows Update issues.

Comment: @STTR: According to [these](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/c0e78d7a-883d-4caa-a8c0-1e127a14612a/windows-7-home-premium-download) [two](http://forums.mydigitallife.info/threads/14709-Windows-7-Digital-River-direct-links-Multiple-Languages-X86-amp-X64/page60) pages **X17-24209.iso** is for **Windows 7 Home Premium x64 English**.

Comment: Found a better list of links [here](http://forums.mydigitallife.info/threads/14709-Windows-7-Digital-River-direct-links-Multiple-Languages-X86-amp-X64/page60), and `X17-24395.iso` is Win7 Ultimate 64-bit pre-SP1. (Edit: Uuugh, 3 hours to download, slow-ass server...)

Comment: @Karan ... wait download `X17-24395.iso` and test)

Comment: @STTR: I'm not gonna test, that's something for the OP to do. :)

Comment: @Polynomial: X17-24395.iso on that page is listed under Win 7 SP1. Note that Win 7 SP1 and Win 7 SP1 *Media Refresh* are two separate releases, with the latter being the latest one. Both have SP1 integrated though. I'm trying to find links to an RTM (pre-SP1) copy of Win7 Ultimate x64 myself. Keep in mind though that as I mentioned above it's quite possible this will all be for naught and the 64-bit only disc will also fail. Did you try sfc?

Comment: Yes, I've tried sfc, it just says it's waiting on a reboot for updates (when there are no updates waiting).

Comment: @Polynomial: Did you try [this Fixit](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/971058)?

Comment: @Karan Yup, no help. Tells me it's done a repair, but doesn't repair anything. Just goes back to "install an update to Windows Update", which fails all the same - error 800B0001

Comment: @Polynomial: Did you try the **System Update Readiness Tool** as suggested [here](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/windows-update-error-800b0001)?

Comment: @Karan From my original question: *"The hotfixes don't work, nor does the Windows update readyness tool, or the manual SP1 upgrade"* - yes, I have already exhausted all options for the Windows Update issue.

Comment: X17-24395.iso finished downloading - it's SP1 integrated :(

Comment: @Polynomial: Ah, I missed that bit. As for the ISO, I told you the page clearly said it was SP1. Finding a link to the RTM version is proving quite difficult indeed, especially since two versions of SP1 have come out after it. I think you might have to do a clean install after all. Might be for the best and will ensure a completely stable system, that even a repair install might not be able to achieve.

Comment: @Polynomial <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> `cmd` If run in cmd: `dir /A:- /S %windir%\Logs\CBS` what see?

Comment: @Karan you can find links to download both SP1 and SP0 Windows 7 ISOs [right here on Super User](http://superuser.com/a/305434/20088)

Comment: @nhinkle: SP0 *Ultimate*?

Comment: @Karan ah - I missed that there isn't a download link for Ultimate. You could however take the SP0 Windows 7 Pro disk and edit the `ei.cfg` file to make it work for Ultimate.

Comment: @nhinkle: True! Was concentrating so hard on obtaining the direct download link for Ultimate that I forgot about that.

Comment: @Polynomial: nhinkle's advice is perfect. Download Win7 RTM Professional or Home Premium ISO from [here](http://superuser.com/a/305434/138343), then use the [Windows 7 ISO Image Edition Switcher](http://code.kliu.org/misc/winisoutils/windows7_iso_image_edition_switcher.zip) (easy way) or edit the **ei.cfg** file manually to convert it to an Ultimate ISO. Hopefully a repair install will work, otherwise I've already told you the alternative more than once...

Comment: Ok, I'll take a look when I get home tonight. Cheers for the help so far all :)

Comment: **UPDATE:** Fixed the original issue, via FixIt 50528. See update to question and my self-answer. Seems everything else was just a wild goose chase.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This issue has now become moot for me - I managed to get Windows Update working again!

So, for anyone with error 800B0001, do the following:

- Download an run the [Windows Update Readiness Tool](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=20858)
- Run the [KB971058 FixIt](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/971058) to ensure that supporting components have been appropriately patched.
- Run [Microsoft FixIt 50528](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/822798) (KB822798) - this is the one that does a FULL repatch of Windows Update. It takes about an hour or two to run, and mostly sits at the "Configuring updates" screen.
- Let the machine fully boot back up after, then immediately shut down and reboot again. It'll go through the update cache and properly install the last set of updates.
- Log back in, go to Windows Update, click "Check for Updates" and wait for it to complete. It may ask you to install an update to Windows Update - if it does ask, do so, and reboot again.

This has resulted in me being able to get Windows Update working again!

Comment: Strange how Fix it 50528 helped you, considering it's listed on a page that supposedly only applies to Win2k, Server 2003 and XP!

Comment: Someone else commented in a (now deleted) answer that Fix-it 50528 also worked for Windows 7 64 bit, with Office 2013.